# CakePHP: do I always need to use isAuthorized()?

Tags: cakephp

As I understand it, CakePHP's `isAuthorized()` function is used to check whether a logged in user has a set of permissions to perform a given action; in other words, it's not for checking whether the user has the right login/password (that's what `login()` is for). Since the app I'm writing doesn't really have any permissions, but just needs to check whether the user is logged in or not, I wrote the following isAuthorized() function:

```
public function isAuthorized() {
    return true;
    }
```

But... it just feels *wrong*. I look at the above function and, frankly, it looks like something out of TheDailyWTF. (And CakePHP complains if I don't have an `isAuthorized()` function, so I can't really delete it).

So I'd just like to ask to make sure that I'm not wrong: if my app only needs to see if an user is logged in or not, without any further permissions, would it be enough with the above function?

Comment: show your Auth setting. You don't need isAuthorized() function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I take it you're using Cake's Auth component since this is where the isAuthorized() function is located.

The quickest way round this would be to define your "allowed actions" in the beforeFilter() of your controller.

For example, to allow all access to all actions:

```
/**
 * Sets all actions to be allowed
 */
public function beforeFilter() {
  parent::beforeFilter();
  if (isset($this->Auth)) {
    $this->Auth->allow('*');
  }
}
```

To allow access to '**index**' & '**view**' actions:

```
/**
 * Allow access to index & view actions
 */
public function beforeFilter() {
  parent::beforeFilter();
  if (isset($this->Auth)) {
    $this->Auth->allowedActions = array('index', 'view');
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Following comments below:

You can set the **authorize** property of the Auth component to 'controller' and then define a callback. So your controller would contain something similar to:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
  parent::beforeFilter();
  $this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';
}

public function isAuthorized() {
  return true; 
}
```

This way, you wouldn't have to change the core and it would do what you needed it to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I was doing to allow access to the login page to everybody. But if, aside of that, I don't have any other "authorization levels" within the app (i.e., if every logged in user can access every page in the site), would be it okay to leave the isAuthorized() function as is? Or could I simply remove it?

Comment: Thanks, I get it now, after thinking about it: "authorization" and "authentication" are different things, and what I need is just authentication. What I've done in the end is to make  $this->Auth->authorize = false. Am I on the right track, or did I miss something else?

Comment: Just for future reference. To allow all actions in cake 2 use **$this->Auth->allow()** withouht the '*'